# Leaflet adding circle says 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet vuejs and importing circle same as javascript code and here is example code from leaflet websites I am using :

```
var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], {
                        color: 'red',
                        fillColor: '#f03',
                        fillOpacity: 0.5,
                        radius: 500
                    }).addTo(this.$refs.map.mapObject);
```

so when I run above code it gives me error :

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`

if I draw polygon that works fine no problem with that.

in console code it also point to this lines :

```
// @method intersects(otherBounds: Bounds): Boolean
// Returns `true` if the rectangle intersects the given bounds. Two bounds
// intersect if they have at least one point in common.

    intersects: function (bounds) { // (Bounds) -> Boolean
        bounds = toBounds(bounds);

        var min = this.min,
            max = this.max,
            min2 = bounds.min,
            max2 = bounds.max,
            xIntersects = (max2.x >= min.x) && (min2.x <= max.x),
            yIntersects = (max2.y >= min.y) && (min2.y <= max.y);

        return xIntersects && yIntersects;
    }
```

I don't know what the bounds it saying as on leaflet website it drawing the circle with same code.

It will be helpful if some can help, you can look this url [Link](https://strato.thisismyaim.com/)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `this.$refs.map.mapObject` is actually a map object? And what version of Leaflet are you using?

Comment: leaflet@^1.3.4, and yes object is same as other things like tiles are working and polygon.